# Wordpress filter not clearly understood

Tags: wordpress, filter, wordpress-theming

I am trying to customize a Wordpress theme. I must to modify the primary menu.

So I assume I have to add a filter to do that. For now I have :

**functions.php :**

```
add_filter( '__header_one_page' , '_one_page_menu');

function _one_page_menu($data) {
  return '<h1>Hello World</h1>';
} //end of _one_page_menu
```

**header.php :**

```
[...]
<?php
apply_filters('__header_one_page', do_action( '__header' ));
?>
```

And the menu is displayed, and no modification.

If someone can help, I guess it's not complicated but I cannot figure out what went wrong.

Thanks by advance,
Le Barde.

Comment: What sort of changment do your want to do on the primay menu ?
Change html structure ?
Add content before the primary menu ?

Explain the most you can

Comment: I want to modify the menu entries. Actually I am implementing a one-page functionality inside the theme, and the header menu needs to be tuned to reflect the page sections instead of the site's main menu.

Comment: Wouldn't you just do that in the Admin?

Comment: No. I want that menu to depend on the sections. My design pattern is, I set one page to be of type "one-page". Then all the child pages are displayed as sections.

Comment: So, the header menu has to be generated depending on the child pages. I assume that is not a problem for the moment: it is modifying the header that I do not know. I already have the page IDs.

Comment: Problem solved. I have found an "apply_filters()" elsewhere in the code that handles the menu. Now it is OK. Thanks for your gentle answers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I am using the Customizr theme, which has a specific filter in `inc/parts/class-header-menu.php`. Here is the code we want to see:

```
/***************************************
* VIEWS
****************************************/
/**
* Menu Rendering : renders the navbar menus, or just the sidenav toggle button
* hook : '__navbar'
*
* @package Customizr
* @since Customizr 3.0
*/
function tc_menu_display() {
  ob_start();

    //renders the regular menu + responsive button
    if ( ! $this -> tc_is_sidenav_enabled() ) {
      $this -> tc_regular_menu_display( 'main' );
    } else {
      $this -> tc_sidenav_toggle_button_display();
      if ( $this -> tc_is_second_menu_enabled() )
        $this -> tc_regular_menu_display( 'secondary' );
      else
        $this -> tc_maybe_display_second_menu_placeholder();
    }

  $html = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  echo apply_filters( 'tc_menu_display', $html );
}
```

Now, we just have to `add_filter( 'tc_menu_display' , '_one_page_menu');` and moodify it.